# Transfer oracle9i table to oracle11g table having all attributes of table oracle9i same

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

1. How to transfer oracle9i table to oracle11g table having all attributes of table same as oracle9i
2. Is there need to make changes in code if any please suggest
3. e.g.,table Customer having bank account which have attributes name ,account number , address ,balance , contact details ,transction date , transction time, etc
4. Suppose this table design in oracle9i and I want to convert it into oracle11g
5. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a couple of tables and a very simple application, just do an exp and imp.

If its a big system, then this is a BIG topic and not something to be taken lightly. Take a look around oracles website, they have quite a lot of documentation on the subject. If  you have never done a database upgrade or migration before, I'd really recommend getting some professional services involved.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no conversion necessary. The 9i table definition will work in 11G. It's just a matter of getting the data from the 9i database to the 11G database. Oracle's imp and exp utilities will get that done.